# Vsts (formerly Visual Studio Online) copy project

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to copy all the elements (source code, work items, ...) from a Vsts project to another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility) that can migrate source code, work items ….

On the other hand, there are [move work items (select some work items > Right click > Move) to another team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items#move-a-work-item-to-another-team-project), [move git repositories between team projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/move-git-repos-between-team-projects), [move items in TFVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rename-move-files-folders) features.

Comment: The opshub one costs some underdermined amount of money, that you have to give up your email address and fill in a form to find out how much :(